# unique quanteda ngrams or textstat_collocations results when return phrases with same words in opposite direction?

Tags: r, n-gram, quanteda

In quanteda text analysing process need to extract 2grams collocations, so normally use `tokens_ngram` or `textstat_collocations` for this job.
as my texts are more than 1000 reviews, this process cause some similar phrase (includes same words) but in opposite directions. note lines 2 and 6 in textstat_collocations results:

```
                collocation count count_nested length   lambda        z
1              street noisy    13            0      2 3.390877 6.963736
2              poor service    11            0      2 2.573747 6.806637
3                 beds hard     5            0      2 5.324351 5.673206
4            extremely rude     4            0      2 3.846168 5.600208
5                room dirty     9            0      2 2.142518 5.482638
6              service poor     8            0      2 2.231967 5.338507
```

is there any way to merge them in a single result and sum the counts?
is there any way to unique quanteda ngrams or textstat_collocations results when return phrases with the same words in the opposite direction?

Answer (score 2):

You can split and recombine each collocation alphabetically, then combine the counts by the new alphabetically reordered collocation.  This will combine the (a, b) and (b, a) combinations in the way that you want.

```r
tab <-
  "                collocation count count_nested length   lambda        z
              'street noisy'    13            0      2 3.390877 6.963736
              'poor service'    11            0      2 2.573747 6.806637
                 'beds hard'     5            0      2 5.324351 5.673206
            'extremely rude'     4            0      2 3.846168 5.600208
                'room dirty'     9            0      2 2.142518 5.482638
              'service poor'     8            0      2 2.231967 5.338507"
ts <- read.table(textConnection(tab), header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library("quanteda")
## Package version: 1.5.2

ts$collocation_sorted <- tokens(ts$collocation) %>% # split the words
  lapply(sort) %>% # sort the words
  sapply(paste, collapse = " ") # recombine
ts
##      collocation count count_nested length   lambda        z collocation_sorted
## 1   street noisy    13            0      2 3.390877 6.963736       noisy street
## 2   poor service    11            0      2 2.573747 6.806637       poor service
## 3      beds hard     5            0      2 5.324351 5.673206          beds hard
## 4 extremely rude     4            0      2 3.846168 5.600208     extremely rude
## 5     room dirty     9            0      2 2.142518 5.482638         dirty room
## 6   service poor     8            0      2 2.231967 5.338507       poor service
```

Now we can use a bit of **dplyr** to sum the count across the new collocation_sorted variable.

```r
library("dplyr")
group_by(ts, collocation_sorted) %>%
  summarise(count = sum(count)) %>%
  arrange(desc(count))
## # A tibble: 5 x 2
##   collocation_sorted count
##   <chr>              <int>
## 1 poor service          19
## 2 noisy street          13
## 3 dirty room             9
## 4 beds hard              5
## 5 extremely rude         4
```